# Patch a method from module imported in the method under test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test (or call it integration test if you want) for my *main* module and `main()` method.

It looks like this:

```python
# main.py in mymodule
# some imports...

def main() -> None:
    # args is a result of argparse parsing
    try:
        if args.type == 'a':
            from mymodule import a
            a.run()
        elif args.type == 'b'
            from mymodule import b
            b.run()
        # elif ...
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Unknown type ' + args.type)
    except (RuntimeError, FileNotFoundError, ...) as e:
        # some logging
        sys.exit(1)

    # some other logging
```

I have tried to mock/patch the modules in these ways:

```
def dummy_run():
    # just do nothing here

def test_main_a(self):
    import mymodule.a
    mymodule.a.run = dummy_run
    os.system('python3 mymodule.main a')
```

and

```
def test_main_a(self):
    # patch is imported as from unittest.mock import patch
    with patch('mymodule.a.run', return_value=None):
        os.system('python3 mymodule.main a')
```

and

```
def test_main_a(self):
    # patch is imported as from unittest.mock import patch
    with patch('mymodule.a.run') as run_mocked:
        run_mocked.return_value = None
        os.system('python3 mymodule.main a')
```

and

```
@patch('mymodule.a.run')
def test_main_a(self, a_mock):
    a_mock.return_value = None
    os.system('python3 mymodule.main a')
```

But all of these ways do not mock/patch the `mymodule.a.run` method ending up in the real method invoked.

When I tried to patch `mymodule.main.a.run` or `mymodule.main.mymodule.a.run` I only got `ModuleNotFoundError`s. I tried these targets after reading the [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) part.

Honestly I do not really understand where is the problem with the patching, as I am patching before the module `mymodule.a` is imported and it's `run()` is called (as this happens only after `os.system('...')` part in the test). Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.system)?

Comment: Of course, I am sorry...will fix

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why you expect it will work as you are using `os.system` to launch another subprocess. So you patch method in current process and expect it will work in another process?

Comment: @Sraw Obviously I was not aware of this behavior. My bad. Thanks for your neat comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patching and mocking only works within the same interpreter, but your call to `os.system('python [...]')` runs the the `main` function in a new interpreter. Instead, you probably want to call the `main` function directly. That might involve patching some `sys` objects like `sys.exit` and `sys.argv`.

However, a common practice is to provide an optional `args` argument to the `main` function:

```
def main(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('type')
    namespace = parser.parse_args(args)
    if namespace.type == 'a':
        from mymodule import a
        a.run()
    sys.exit()
```

This way, one can easily inject and test command-line arguments:

```
def test_main_a():
    with patch('mymodule.a.run') as run_mocked:
        main(['a'])
```

Also, the [pytest.raises](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) context can be used to manage the call to `sys.exit`:

```
def test_main_a():
    with patch('mymodule.a.run') as run_mocked:
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            main(['a'])
```

Comment: Do you suggest using the `pytest` library instead of the native `unittest`? What are the advantages? So far I have all my unittests written using the native library (with overall 87.8% coverage). Thanks!

Comment: @shadyyx It's a different question, and quite a subjective one. But in my opinion, it is much nicer to write tests using pytest. Also note that the pytest runner [supports unittest.TestCase](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html), so you don't have to rewrite all your tests. You can simply start writing extra tests with pytest and see how you like it.

Comment: I have one problem though. I have rewritten the `main()` method as you have suggested, and running selective tests from the suite works without a problem. However, if I run the whole suite at once, I get ~50% of the tests failed when trying to setup the logging, telling me that `log = logging.getLogger('mymodule')` followed by `handler = logging.StreamHandler(stderr)` and `log.addHandler(handler)` fails in `AttributeError: 'CustomAdapter' object has no attribute 'addHandler'`. This happens always when I have my test to run `main.main(args)` not commented out... Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @shadyyx It really depends on how your logging system is set up, so I can't really help you with that.